# No hard drive detected during ubuntu 19.04 installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dell, raid, ahci

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 19.04 on a 2019 Dell [Inspiron 7490](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-14-7490-laptop_users-guide_en-us.pdf) ([service manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/inspiron-14-7490-laptop/inspiron-7490-service-manual/working-inside-your-computer?guid=guid-dd3ae169-a824-4f1d-832e-585b176f6faf&lang=en-us)). When I get to the point of selecting a partition to install on, the installer can't find any hard drive and I just see an empty list like this:

[image: here].

I found this information from Dell about the issue:
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en

Although its a bit outdated. They suggest to first set the SATA operation to AHCI in BIOS. In my BIOS I don't get an option for AHCI as seen below:

[image: here]

Only disabled or RAID. To my understanding, AHCI is a type of RAID so maybe this is the correct setting. Thoughts?

Next, the Dell page suggests changing the Ubuntu boot options to include `nvme_load=YES`. I have not been able to do this as when I boot the installer from my USB I never see the keyboard prompt so I am unable to enter the menu where they change the boot options.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions regarding this? I don't need to keep the Windows installation so solutions that involve removing Windows are also welcome.

Comment: Just letting you know that a newer version, 19.10, was released today.

Comment: `Intel Rapid Restore Technology` is a windows thing, so you need to find a way to disable it first. It does not play well with Ubuntu. Although not totally impossible to install Ubuntu with `Intel Rapid Restore Technology` enabled.

Comment: Please open a terminal window, and run lspci -v so we can see what hardware you have. Copy the results and come back here then click [edit] and paste them into your question.

Comment: any update on this? I have the similar situation that the machine is shipped with `Windows 11`, and I want to re-install the Ubuntu 18, but can't see the disk drive either in Ubuntu installation wizard, my BIOS does not have an option of AHCI mode enable or disable.

Answer (score 2):

[AHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) is *not* a form of RAID; it adds capabilities in communicating to a SATA drive, but not RAID.

Until the drives appear in the BIOS/firmware setup, nothing you do will work in any OS. This is a firmware issue specific to this model of Dell, so I would ask Dell Support to get the drive to appear in BIOS/firmware setup.